# A tool to format text with Unicode combining characters l̲i̲k̲e̲ t̅h̅i̅s̅

Tags: plain-text, text-processing, unicode

Unicode enables some formatting in plain text using combining characters like `U+0332 COMBINING LOW LINE`: E̲x̲a̲m̲p̲l̲e̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲d̲ ̲t̲e̲x̲t̲.

How do I do it automatically, without manually inserting U+0332 after each character?

Preferrably free/open source or online.

Comment: Those underlines and overlines look really ugly...

Comment: But they may work even when formatting is otherwise not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Implemented myself: https://gist.github.com/vi/2d6b268cc243c138358f3d1b88120ff5

```
$ formatunicode '-Check- Test of ^the^ _tool_'
C̶h̶e̶c̶k̶ Test of t̅h̅e̅ t̲o̲o̲l̲
```

One may need to add additional temporary letters or spaces to workaround non-recognition of patterns.

If one needs reverse transformation, post a comment.